# Troubleshooting TV tuner problems

Tags: drivers, hardware, tv-tuner

I've been using a TBS6281SE TV tuner without issues for a couple of months, after installing [TBS's fork](https://github.com/tbsdtv/linux_media/wiki) of the LinuxTV open source drivers from GitHub.

Today the tuner has stopped showing up in the system. It is listed by `lspci`, but not by `lsdvb` (the latter reports an error opening `/sys/class/dvb`). There is no obvious issue reported in `dmesg`, and, naturally, the tuner isn't recognised by TVheadend.

I haven't made any changes to the system recently. I tried re-building and installing the driver, and installing available software updates from `apt upgrade`, but nothing has helped.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.3, with kernel version 4.4.0.

What steps can I take to determine what has gone wrong? How should I attempt to get it working again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Working out what went wrong

Looking through the APT history log `/var/log/apt/history.log` I was able to determine that unattended upgrades had updated the Linux kernel from 4.4.0-104 to 4.4.0-112.

```
Start-Date: 2018-01-24  06:36:09
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Install: linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-112.135, automatic)
```

The system hadn't been rebooted until immediately before the tuner stopped working, and so I assume that this was the first time the newer kernel was used.

Booting from the previous kernel at the Grub menu confirmed this was the cause, and I was able to re-build the driver for the kernel I'd used initially.

### Getting it working again

Kernel version 4.4.0-110 included a host of changes to (I assume) address the Meltdown/Spectre vulnerabilities, so it makes sense to use the latest version for the added security and peace of mind it should provide.

The solution was to rebuild the driver as before, but using a fresh `media_build` directory. This ensured the modules were compiled and installed for the current kernel.